# Not getting array output from jquery to php laravel post method

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

**MY HTML CODE :-**

```
                            <div class="row form-row education-cont">
                                <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-11">
                                    <div class="row form-row">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Degree</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="degree" class="form-control">
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>College/Institute</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="clg" class="form-control">
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label>Year of Completion</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="yoc[]" class="form-control">
                                            </div> 
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

---

**I use templete of html from online the jquery code:-**

```
$(".education-info").on('click','.trash', function () {
        $(this).closest('.education-cont').remove();
        // edu--;
        return false;
    });

    $(".add-education").on('click', function () {
        // edu++;
        var educationcontent = '<div class="row form-row education-cont">' +
            '<div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-11">' +
                '<div class="row form-row">' +
                    '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">' +
                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                            '<label>Degree</label>' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control">' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">' +
                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                            '<label>College/Institute</label>' +
                            '<input type="text" class="form-control">' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">' +
                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                            '<label>Year of Completion</label>' +
                            '<input type="text" name="yoc[]" class="form-control">' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-12 col-md-2 col-lg-1"><label class="d-md-block d-sm-none d-none">&nbsp;</label><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger trash"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a></div>' +
        '</div>';
        
        $(".education-info").append(educationcontent);
        return false;
    });
```

---

**now the laravel post method for controller is :-**

```
       public function drprofilesettingpost(Request $request){
                 $yoc = $request->yoc;
                 dd($yoc);
          }
```

---

**i am not getting a yoc name field(as year of compeletion) output only getting first array output only , i want all dynamically added field output the output i am getting**

```
        array:1 [▼
          0 => "1234"
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with code. You can make changes as per this example and try

*I have used my demo controller route (demo.store) you need to replace it with your route in the form*

**in blade file**

```
<form action="{{ route('demo.store') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf

        <div class="row form-row education-cont mb-2">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-11">
                <div class="row form-row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Degree</label>
                            <input type="text" name="degree[]" value="" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>College/Institute</label>
                            <input type="text" name="clg[]" value="" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Year of Completion</label>
                            <input type="text" name="yoc[]" value="" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="education-info"></div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <a class="btn btn-success add-education">Add Education</a>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </div>

</form>
```

in controller

here I have used store function you can use your function

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $all_degrees = [];

        if($request->input('degree') && !empty($request->input('degree'))){
            $clg_array = $request->input('clg');
            $yoc_array = $request->input('yoc');

            foreach ($request->input('degree') as $key => $value) {
                $temp = [];

                $temp['degree'] = $value;
                $temp['clg'] = $clg_array[$key];
                $temp['yoc'] = $yoc_array[$key];

                $all_degrees[] = $temp;
            }
        }

        dd($all_degrees);
    }
```

sample output

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "degree" => "BCA"
    "clg" => "KSV"
    "yoc" => "2012"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "degree" => "MCA"
    "clg" => "KSV"
    "yoc" => "2017"
  ]
]
```